# Can I iterate over complete strings in a list using a nested for loop?

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to zip two lists together by iterating over them in a nested for loop but it is iterating over each character instead of the entire string. Here is what I have tried:

```
lengths = ['30', '15', '10']
tags = ['tom', 'tod']

combined = [list(zip(a,b)) for a in lengths for b in tags]
print(combined)
```

Output:

```
[[('3', 't'), ('0', 'o')], [('3', 't'), ('0', 'o')], [('1', 't'), ('5', 'o')], [('1', 't'), ('5', 'o')], [('1', 't'), ('0', 'o')], [('1', 't'), ('0', 'o')]]
```

The output I need:

```
[[('30'), ('tom')], [('30'), ('tod')], [('15'), ('tom')], [('15'), ('tod')], [('10'), ('tom')], [('10'), ('tod')]]
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: The parentheses in your desired output are redundant; `('30')` is equivalent to `'30'`.

Comment: As such, you just need `[list(z) for z in itertools.product(lengths, tags)]`. Or just `[list((a, b)) for a in lengths for b in tags]`; drop the call to `zip`.

Comment: The problem here isn't with the iteration, but with the processing done each time through the loop. `list(zip(a,b))` here makes **no sense at all**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a [nested list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions):

```
result = [[length, tag] for length in lengths for tag in tags]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[['30', 'tom'], ['30', 'tod'], ['15', 'tom'], ['15', 'tod'], ['10', 'tom'], ['10', 'tod']]
```

Also as @chepner mentioned the parentheses are redundant, so you don't need them.

Comment: That's not a nested list comprehension; `[length, tag]` is just a list literal, not a comprehension.